# jQuery Spinner Change Database

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery, spinner

my first time posting here. I'm hoping someone can help me.

So can someone give me an example on how to update mysql database after a ui spinner has been changed? I've been doing more php than javascript (so i kind of forgot some of it)and I haven't used jQuery, but it looks simple, I'm just not sure how to do something after the spinner has been changed. I know Ajax is gonna be used, but can someone explain how you would do this..

```
<?php buncha php code here.. connected to database ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script jquerylinkhere></script>
        <script jqueryuilinkhere></script>
        <script>
         $(function() {
             var urmom = $( ".spinner" ).spinner();
             **not sure what goes here to send info to database**
         });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        <?php loops by amount stored in database table { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $query["id"]; ?></td>
            <td>
                <input class="spinner" name="value" value="<?php echo $query["value"]; ?>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
     <?php } ?>
    </table>
    </body>
 </html>
```

I already created a table in the database named "products" with columns "id" and "value"
currently there is 5 products and they all have the value of 0.

So everytime I change the spinner then leave that spinner for another, I want the new value
to be added to the database.

Thanks

Comment: Each time the spinner is changed or each time the spinner loses it's focus? That's an important difference.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: sorry forgot. when it loses focus, i think every time it spins would be a little too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My jQuery isn't the best, but I think this should help you a little.

```
urmom.focusout(function() {
    $.ajax(LinkToYourPHPScript, {
        data: { Value : urmom.value() },
        type: 'POST'
    });
});
```

This script will (if my 'head compiler' doesn't fail me right now), react to the focusout event and call the Ajax function, which will put the current (formatted) value of the spinner in the `$_POST['Value']` variable.

Again, this code is completely untested.

On a side note 'urmom' isn't exactly a very good variable name. I agree that it often is difficult to find good variable names, but `spn` is far more fitting for a `spinner` than `urmom`. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: aha that looks like it'll work, ill try it out later, i'm about to head off to work. i'm not really using "urmom" it was just the first thing that came to mind when i was typing this. Thanks for your help